# how can I change web application without changing the app with expo

Tags: react-native, expo, progressive-web-apps

I have an expo react native project which works perfectly fine on every android device that I have tried. 
but when I tried to build a pwa version of the project with `expo build:web` , the components renders in a totally wrong position and the output is not acceptable at all. 
I want to know if anyone has the same problem with expo web builds, and how you manage to fix this problem. 
is there any way that I change the implementation of the web application without changing the output of android app? 
thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use **Platform Specific Code** with  https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code

With your situation, it will be something like this

```
HeaderBar.js         # Webpack, Rollup or any other Web bundler
HeaderBar.native.js  # React Native bundler for both Android and iOS (Metro)
HeaderBar.android.js # Android only
```